# Install ROS on Windows

Tags: ros, windows, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am trying to install ROS on windows from the "http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/groovy/Msvc%20Compiled%20SDK".
I have installed all the dependencies as stated in this link, but still not able to write command "winros_init_workspace"....it shows that "winros_init_workspace" is not recognised as an internal or external command.

I know that ROS is not fully compatible with windows, but i just wanted to create one subscriber to get values only.

Please help to sove this, I am thanking you all in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219150/install-ros-on-windows/) by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you execute the
setup.bat

this init all envirument vars
greet Anton,

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1